# Can I make SSH ForwardAgent and ProxyJump work with Git?

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-agent

I have two computers; my workstation and a laptop I use to run my company VPN. I need to go through the VPN in order to reach my Git remote (BitBucket).

I have an SSH agent running on my workstation that contains the SSH key needed to connect to the Git remote. I have configured SSH to forward my SSH agent when connecting to my laptop:

```
Host my-laptop
    ForwardAgent yes
```

If I use SSH to connect to my laptop, I can successfully `git pull`, and `ssh-agent -l` confirms that the SSH agent was properly forwarded. So far so good!

Here's the challenge: I want to use git directly from my workstation. This should be possibly by configuring SSH to proxy through my laptop. My git remotes look like this:

```
➜ git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@bitbucket.my-company.com:7999/my-team/my-project.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@bitbucket.my-company.com:7999/my-team/my-project.git (push)
```

So I added this SSH configuration:

```
Host *.my-company.com
    ProxyJump my-laptop
```

The proxy jump worked, because now I reach the Git remote!

However, authentication fails:

> git@bitbucket.my-company.com: Permission denied (publickey).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.
> exit status 128

So apparently SSH agent forwarding didn't work when proxying the command..?

Troubleshooting steps I have tried:

- Connecting to the laptop with SSH and running `git pull` - it works
- Running `git pull` directly from the laptop - it works
- Adding `IdentityFile` and `IdentitiesOnly` to force the right key to be used, didn't make a difference:

  ```
  Host *.my-company.com
      ProxyJump my-laptop
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/hubro@my-company.com.key
      IdentitiesOnly yes
  ```
- Adding `ForwardAgent yes` when connecting to the Git remote host, didn't make a difference:

  ```
  Host *.my-company.com
      ProxyJump my-laptop
      ForwardAgent yes
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/hubro@my-company.com.key
      IdentitiesOnly yes
  ```

So why isn't my local SSH agent being used when running git commands?

Comment: It seems likely that the use of this ProxyJump config *doesn't* do agent forwarding because you're running `ssh user@host.my-company.com`, not `ssh user@my-laptop`. Telling ssh to do agent forwarding in the other config or with `-A` will probably let you proceed (I have not tried this myself). However, see also http://unixetc.co.uk/2017/11/13/ssh-proxying-and-agent-forwarding/ - or the "tl;dr" caveat that when using agent forwarding, you're giving your keys to any super-user on the intermediate system. (Probably not too big a concern *here*.)

Comment: @torek That makes sense, but I tried it and unfortunately it didn't make a difference

Comment: In that case, see the link anyway - it gives you a different way to deal with this.

Comment: Please try `ssh -vvv git@bitbucket.my-company.com -p7999` and show the results, perhaps you have too many possible keys

Comment: @jeb It says "debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm" for the correct key 

Comment: I just read about the error message: `In the event that you are using an operating system or SSH client whose version has this algorithm (ssh-rsa) disabled`. Are you using the same keys on both computers? Take a look into the private -key files

Comment: I see, it seems like ssh-rsa signatures are being deprecated. Since I'm running Arch on my workstation I have a bleeding-edge version of SSH, so it seems ssh-rsa is already disabled on my system. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/226131/openssh-declares-ssh-rsa-deprecated-what-do-i-do-next. I guess I'll generate a new key and try again.

Comment: @jeb Confirmed! I replaced my SSH key with a ssh-ed25519 type SSH key (`ssh-keygen -t ed25519`) and now it works! The problem all along was my system being too up-to-date 

Comment: You should add that as an own answer, you won't be the only one with that problem

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I don't even need SSH agent forwarding in this setup, since the ProxyJump setting sets up a tunnel that lets my workstation communicate "directly" with the git remote.

The reason I was getting "Permission denied (publickey)" errors turns out to be that my distribution (Arch) is extremely up-to-date and have already disabled support for "ssh-rsa" keys by default. (At time of writing, Arch linux ships with openssh 8.8p1)

Frustratingly, it doesn't matter that I generate my key with "rsa-sha2-512", which should be secure, my SSH client still won't have it.

However, I generated a new key using ed25519 instead, and that solved my problem.

```sh
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need agent forwarding in your case, because you don't want to forward your key to the bitbucket.my-company.com server, you only want to authenticate there.

*Forwarding* a key owned by an intermediate proxy is not possible with `ForwardAgent`.

You need the correct key on your workstation, but it looks like that the key is only present on your laptop (`Running git pull directly from the laptop - it works`).

1. You could copy the private key from your laptop to your workstation
2. You can forward the key from the laptop to your workstation in one terminal and use that key with git in another terminal

Comment: I definitely have the key on my workstation as well. It's loaded into my local SSH agent. If I SSH to my laptop *with ForwardAgent enabled* I can `git pull` from successfully from the git remote. If I SSH to my laptop with ForwardAgent *disabled* (`ssh -o ForwardAgent=no ...`) then `git pull` fails.

Comment: @Hubro But you wrote that it also works if you are use it directly from your laptop without ForwardAgent from your workstation

Comment: Sorry, when I said "directly from the laptop" I meant physically on the laptop, not through SSH. I have an SSH agent on the laptop with the same SSH key added. When I open a terminal directly on the laptop, the local SSH agent is used. When I SSH to the laptop with SSH agent forwarding disabled, then no SSH agent is used and `git pull` fails. I'm not sure why it works that way.

Comment: @Hubro How many keys are stored in the agent on the laptop and on the workstation? You could try also `ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes git@bitbucket.my-company.com -p7999`